# Losing float precision within the dictionary

Tags: python, json

```
jsons = json.loads(request.data)
```

jsons -->

```
dict: {u'json_event': {u'timestamp': 1408878136.318921}}
```

and

```
json_event = jsons['json_event']
```

json_event -->

```
dict: {u'timestamp': 1408878136.318921}
```

However when I do `json_event['timestamp']`
I only get two decimal places precision:

```
float: 1408878136.32
```

Is there a way to keep the precision?

**Update:**

I don't think this is a representation problem.

```
event, is_created = Event.create_or_update(json_event['event_id'],
                                           timestamp=json_event['timestamp'])


class Event(ndb.Model):
     ...
     timestamp = ndb.FloatProperty(required=True)
```

`event.timestamp --> 1408878136.32`

Comment: [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: you are using `print json_event['timestamp']`?

Comment: I have updated the question with more details. @R.T. but I need the precision for timestamps, what is the solution?

Comment: Your update still does not discount representation problem. You have to show the complete statements you use to print the values.

Comment: Perhaps you are right. When I check Google App Engine's dashboard it shows me only two precision points for timestamp. Is there a way to test this or do I have to assume the dashboard represents only 2 decimal places?

Comment: @Hooman: The dashboard apparently only represents 12 significant digits, because that's what calling `str` on floating point number does in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you—or whatever tool you use to print the numbers—uses standard conversion to string, only 12 significant digits get printed:

```
>>> str(1408878136.318921)
'1408878136.32'
```

But when you use the `repr` builtin, enough significant digits get printed to ensure identical value would be read back by python parser:

```
>>> repr(1408878136.318921)
'1408878136.318921'
```

So just wrap whatever you are printing in a manual `repr()` call.

This is just representational issue. Obviously the JSON printer uses some logic (may be via `repr` or may not) to print enough digits to read back the same value. But the tool you are using to print them is not.

Note that the logic is pretty complex, because binary fractional numbers don't correspond exactly to decimal fractional numbers. `0.3` has periodic representation in binary and thus if you read `0.3`, the actual number stored will have slightly different value. And a closest decimal representation is different. So the logic has to consider how much rounding it can apply to still read back the correct value.